# debug in javafx without a main method

Tags: java, javafx

I have just started using Javafx and I have enjoyed it so far. However I wanted to do some de-bugging with it, and I get this error.
Error: Main method not found in class fx.MyProgram, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

If I go ahead and add a main method... the body is empty because all the magic happens from button clicks from the View. Do I need to change some configurations? Running the app works fine, but de-bugging doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

nvm I figured it out myself. For anyone else who runs into this...

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Application.launch(args);
}
```